# Console App wont display items from List C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, crud

My program won't display items from List. It works when i make the list static, but the problem requires me to solve it without using that keyword.Otherwise I'd use static.Here is my code,a part of it atleast. I'm trying basically to implement CRUD, but i am using list for now. Much of the other code follows a similar pattern, so I am stuck here now. Any tips would be appreciated.Thanks.

```
   public class Storage<T> where T : BaseModel
    {

        public List<T> list;


        public Storage()
        {
            list = new List<T>();
        }



        public void Add(T model)
        {
            list.Add(model);
        }

        public List<T> Get()
        {
            return list;
        }

        public void Remove(String FirstName, String LastName, int Age)
        {
            list.RemoveAll(x => x.FirstName == FirstName && x.LastName == LastName && x.Age == Age);
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }


    public class CEOService
    {


        public Storage<CEO> storeCEO = new Storage<CEO>();

        public void Add(String FirstName, String LastName, int Age, int CeoYears)
        {
            foreach (CEO c in storeCEO.Get())
            {
                int count = storeCEO.Get().Count;
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("CEO already exists, there can only be one! ");
                    return;
                }
            }
            CEO ceo = new CEO();

            ceo.FirstName = FirstName;

            ceo.LastName = LastName;

            ceo.Age = Age;

            ceo.CeoYears = CeoYears;

            storeCEO.Add(ceo);
        }

        public List<CEO> Get()
        {
            return storeCEO.Get();
        }

        public void Remove(String FirstName, String LastName, int Age)
        {
            storeCEO.Remove(FirstName, LastName, Age);
        }


    }



 public class ShowEmployees
{


    public CEOService CEOService = new CEOService();




    public void CEOList()
    {
        foreach (CEO c in CEOService.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Age);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why cant you use static?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: @BugFinder because the task is to do it without it

Comment: The reason is that in `ShowEmployees` you create a new instance of `CEOService`, which is empty. Any information you added to a previous instance isn't available in this new instance. It's difficult to say what changes you need to make because the code you present is not complete.

Comment: You should write the code block starting at `foreach (CEO c in storeCEO.Get())` in plain english and read it out loud.  Foreach CEO, lets say 100, Lets count them every time. If there is only one, display display and error message. Pick the next CEO. You don't need the foreach and the if should have a `>` or an `<`

Comment: @JimMischel Thank You, it was sucha stupid mistake :)